# Getting items from start in MultiAutoCompleteTextView when using custom adaptor in android instead of correct start place?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, autofill, multiautocompletetextview

I have created a custom adaptor for MultiAutoCompleteTextView, which gives me view for list view. The problem is that when ever i type any character, it gives right count, but starting index start from 0 hence i see wrong names.

```
    String[] personsList = {"Rahul", "Mike", "Mantu","Mathew", "Gatr", "Ahamad"};
    AutoCompleteNameAdaptor autoCompleteAdaptor = new AutoCompleteNameAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), personsList);
    CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView personName = (CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.allPeopleInvolved);
    personName.setThreshold(1);
    personName.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdaptor);
    personName.setTokenizer(new CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

When list view opens it always show list item start from "Rahul, even when i type "m", but count remains 3, so 3 items comes starting from item 0.

This is working fine in android arrayAdaptor which is :

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, personsList);
```

Were should i debug to get why it is not passing right indexes in getView function of my adaptor, or do i need to setup some sorting algorithm to sort list and update it in adaptor again, if yes where?

Custom Adaptor Code

```
public class AutoCompleteNameAdaptor  extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

LayoutInflater inflater;
String[] listItems;

public AutoCompleteNameAdaptor(Context context, String[] objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.people_involved_autocomplete_list, objects);
    this.listItems = objects;
     inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GenericItemViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.people_involved_autocomplete_list, parent, false);
        holder = new GenericItemViewHolder();
        holder.personNameLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personName);
        holder.personNameLabel.setText(this.listItems[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (GenericItemViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return this.listItems[position];
}

public static class GenericItemViewHolder {
    public TextView personNameLabel;
    public ImageView personNameImage;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Applied my own custom filter

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null)
        filter = new AutoCompleteFilter(listItems);
    return filter;
}
```

Added my own logic in function performFiltering.

Also in getView function if (convertView == null)  is not needed, as it will always show cached value if we check only for null and show if position element is present.